# Condition inside the SUM

Tags: mysql

I have created the following query but what I exactly want is that instead of `SUM( credit - debit ) AS del` 
I need `SUM( credit - SUM of debit (Start Counting debit after transaction where description is 'Earned' ) AS del`. 
For example from following query I am getting debit values which was inserted before the transaction where description is 'Earned' and I want to SUM debit column after the transaction 'Earned' is inserted in the table

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e46/4

```
    SELECT user_id, 'Removed', 0, SUM( credit - debit ) AS del, 0, NOW( ), NOW( ) 
FROM accounts
WHERE created
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( NOW( ) ) +6
DAY ) 
AND DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( NOW( ) ) -1
DAY ) 
AND (
description LIKE  '%Earned%'
OR description =  'S'
OR description =  'B'
)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING del > 0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show a sample data in sql-fiddle?

Comment: How about some sample data and an expected result to go with it?

Comment: I have added the images, in this case debit should be 3, but above query output 5 against user_id 01

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e46/4